# Hall $\pi$-subgroup of a minimal normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $B$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ and suppose that $H \in$ Hall$_\pi$($B$).

Then $B = S_1 \times \dots \times S_n$ where $S_i$ are simple groups. I'm not sure how $H = \langle H \cap S_i \;| \;i =1,\dots, n\rangle$

Clearly, $\langle H \cap S_i \;| \;i =1,\dots, n\rangle \leq H$, but I can't seem to show the other inclusion.

Comment: It is not in general (take for example the diagonal subgroup in $C_p\times C_p$).

Comment: Okay thanks I will edit my question to be more specific

Comment: Hmm, so projecting onto each factor should show that $H$ is a Hall subgroup of each $S_i$, right?

Comment: Do mean if I consider for instance $p_1 : B \longrightarrow S_1$, I would only get that $p_1(H)$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $S_1$ and not $H$. I'm not sure how the intersection $H \cap S_i$ come about

Comment: Right, so it seems (though I did not consider this thoroughly) that it must in fact have the same size intersection with each $S_i$ (since all the $S_i$ are isomorphic).

Comment: I am still not sure how this shows that $H \leq \langle H \cap S_i \rangle$

Comment: If you can show that the intersection with each $S_i$ is a $\pi$-Hall subgroup of $S_i$ then it will follow by just considering the order.

Comment: In general, if $H \in {\rm Hall}_\pi(G)$ and $N \unlhd G$, then $H \cap N \in {\rm Hall}_\pi(N)$.

Comment: $S_i \unlhd B$ and $H \in$ Hall$_\pi$($B$) so $H\cap S_i \in$ Hall$_\pi$($S_i$). I'm stuck on determining the order of $\langle H\cap S_i \; |\; i = 1, \ldots, n\rangle$. I only know that it contains atleast $n|H \cap S_1|$ elements

Comment: I don't see the problem. It is easy to see that this order is the product of the $|H \cap S_i|$, which is the same as the order of a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $B$.

Comment: My problem lies in showing that $|\langle H\cap S_i \rangle|$ = $\prod_{i=1}^{n} |H \cap S_i|$. I just can't seem to get it

Comment: Do you see that it is at least that large?

Comment: Yes, Since $ AB \subseteq \langle A, B \rangle$

Comment: Then what is the problem? That is already the order of a $\pi$-Hall subgroup which $H$ is assumed to be.